# Bitwise & operator in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I'm stuck with Snowflake about bitwise operators. In MySql it's allowed to use this syntax:

```
Flag & 1024 > 0
```

I'd like to make the same filtering in the where clause with Snowflake but I've found only these function on the web:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/expressions-byte-bit.html

Do you have any ideal how to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Flag & 1024 > 0` is equivalent of [BITWISE AND](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/bitand.html):

```
WHERE BITAND(Flag, 1024) > 0;
```

[db<> fiddle demo MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37bf021a4d92a582915a95089852e919)

Snowflake:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(flag INT)
AS
SELECT 1024 AS flag
UNION SELECT 2048
UNION SELECT 1025;

SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE BITAND(Flag, 1024) > 0;
-- 1024
-- 1025
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my guess but I wasn't 100% sure :)